# Eclipse won't find any MinGW files

Tags: c++, eclipse, windows, gcc, mingw

So like a lot of people, I'm getting these errors when I try to run my project:

Program "g++" not found in PATH

Program "gcc" not found in PATH

Program "make" not found in PATH

Now I've tried everything I've found and nothing thus far has worked. The other day I figured out that I didn't have any MinGW files for some reason and I installed that, put its path in the PATH variable, and it got rid of the g++ and gcc errors, but for some reason they have returned.

I've tried:

-explicitly setting the path to the MinGW bin folder

-fiddling around with the different toolchains

-cleaning and refreshing the project

-opening and closing the project

-running eclipse in administrator mode

-restarting eclipse

-restarting computer

None of these had any effect. Just for an extra bit of info I did import the project from a github repository with a new make file, and I am running Windows 10 64 bit. Any help with this would be appreciated, I've spent more time on it than I care to admit.

Comment: What happens with a fresh mingw hello world C++ project?

Comment: That seems to be able to build for some reason. Do you think I should just take the source code and make it into an entirely new project instead of importing it?

Comment: Yeah. Start with that. Existing code as makefile project should do what you need. Something in the project configuration seems to expect mingw to be installed a particular place and manner. The .cproject file is all text so odds are good you can hunt down the bad parameters, but there may be more pieces that need to be adjusted. Warning on make, though, it doesn't (or didn't. This may have changed) ship with the default mingw installs. You may need to download msys to get make.

Comment: So I remade the project, downloaded msys, and linked the environment to it. After a little more tinkering I was able to get it to run, but, it doesn't run like it should. At this point I've just downloaded visual studio and I'm going to continue the project there so that I can get to work. Hopefully if I just use he source files it will all work out. Thanks for your help, I probably wouldn't have gotten this far without it.